# pushd > /dev/null permission denied in .zshrc

Tags: linux, shell, zsh, zshrc

I'm using the commands `pushd` and `popd` in my `.zshrc`. I don't want these two commands to print anything to the console.

Therefore I tried to use it this way: `pushd > /dev/null`.
But now the output is: `permission denied: /etc/null`.

`> /dev/null/` works for all other commands directly typed into my console (this tells me, that the permissions on `/dev` should be set correctly).

Comment: Are you certain you didn't accidentally type `pushd > /etc/null`?

Comment: Oh god, that typo was really the mistake... Thank you! I should really go to bed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keith Thompson mentioned, I accidentally typed `> /etc/null` instead of `> /dev/null`

Fixing that typo solved my problem. 
I should have better read the output:

> permission denied: /**etc**/null